# Extracting top-level domain names from list of website addresses

Tags: java, php, mysql

I have a list of web addresses such as listed below in my DB.

I need to get the domain name from each address in the list.

- `http://en.wordpress.com/tag/1000-things-we-hate/`
- `http://en.wordpress.com/tag/1019/`
- `http://en.wordpress.com/tag/1030-am/`
- `http://www.yahoo.com/index.html`
- `http://www.msn.com/index.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it in Java:

```
String input = "http://en.wordpress.com/tag/1000-things-we-hate/";
// Assuming that all urls start with "http://"
int finish = input.indexOf("/", 7);
if(finish == -1)
{
  finish = input.length();
}
System.out.println(input.substring(7, finish));
```

Prints `en.wordpress.com` (I assume that is what you want?)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url = "http://en.wordpress.com/tag/1000-things-we-hate/";
$bits = explode("/",$url);
$nextBits = explode(".",$bits[1]);
$count = count($nextBits);
$domain = $nextBits[$count-1].".".$nextBits[$count];
echo $domain;
?>
```

Comment: There are bugs in that code. It doesn't work as intended.

Even if it would work as intended, it would not be sufficient. "http://bbc.co.uk/" would return "co.uk"

Comment: there are 2 collections of TLDs that I found https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8ALaar6dLM7ZUc2MUtidVE4RXM/edit?usp=sharing
and
http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

That would return "en.wordpress.com". If you don't want subdomains (i.e. only "wordpress.com), then things are getting complicated. You would need something like http://www.dkim-reputation.org/regdom-libs/

Answer (score 0):

Use the [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) in PHP.